# PHPExcel_Style_Protection not found

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to implement this code to lock and unlock an excel sheet.

```
$sheet->getProtection()->setPassword('password hare');
$sheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
$sheet->getStyle('A1:B2')->getProtection()
->setLocked(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
```

I am getting an error

> "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PHPExcel_Style_Protection' not found"

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
->setLocked(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
->setLocked(\PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
```